# How to get status from Monit from a NodeJS program?

Tags: node.js, monit

I'm trying to get the status from Monit from a NodeJS program.  In my monitrc I have it set to use port 2812, but I'm not sure what to do in my node program.  Any advice would be highly appreciated.

I'll add that I am currently clueless, but I've tried:

```
var net = require('net');

var client = net.connect({port: 2812},
    function() { //'connect' listener
  console.log('client connected');
  client.write('monit status');
});
client.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log(data.toString());
  client.end();
});
client.on('end', function() {
  console.log('client disconnected');
});
```

Which outputs:

```
client connected
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
Date: Tue, 04 Dec 2012 17:03:15 GMT
Server: monit 5.3.2
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: close

<html><head><title>Bad Request</title></head><body bgcolor=#FFFFFF><h2>Bad Request</h2>Cannot parse request<p><hr><a href='http://mmonit.com/monit/'><font size=-1>monit 5.3.2</font></a></body></html>

client disconnected
```

This is more than nothing, since it actually lists monit as the server, but I have no idea how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Turns out what I wanted to do was:

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
  hostname: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 2812,
  method: 'GET'
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + data);
  });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

req.end();
```

Comment: Also it didn't really do what I wanted to do, I didn't quite understand what was possible to do through connecting to monit via a port.  But at least this works.